# Show that there exists a unique continuous linear map

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let H be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis {$e_n$}.Suppose
that elements $h_{n} \  \ (n = 1, 2, . . .)$ of H are given such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} ||h_{n}||^2 < \infty$.
Show that there exists a unique continuous linear map $T : H → H$ such that
$T e_{n} = h_{n} \ (n = 1, 2, . . .)$.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Maybe something like $Tx = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} h_{i}(x, e_{i})e_{i}$. Also how to use the separability of H?

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there are two such maps $T,T'$. Then there exists an $x$ in your space such that $Tx\neq T'x$. Write $x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle e_i,x\rangle e_i$. Show that you can exchange $T$ with the sum, which gives: $Tx=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle e_i,x\rangle h_i$. Consider the finite sum $\sum_{i=1}^N \langle e_i,x\rangle h_i$ and show that it converges to the infinite sum. This will allow you to conclude that $Tx=T'x$ which implies $T$ must be unique.

Comment: We can write $x$ like that because of Parsevals identity right?

Comment: Parseval's identity relates the norm of $x$ to its norm calculated through its basis expansion. This is more of a consequence of orthonormal basis and Bessel's inequality (which becomes an equality when your sum is infinite and over your basis): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Bessel.27s_inequality_and_Parseval.27s_formula

Comment: How does this show existence of $T$ in the question?

Comment: @copper.hat $T$ is given as $Tx=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle e_i,x\rangle h_i$.

Comment: @Fightclub1995: I understand that, but you need to show that it is a bounded operator.

Comment: @copper.hat That shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: @Fightclub1995: The question asked to show existence and uniqueness, The above is correct, but just deals with uniqueness. Showing existence needs some more work. It is not particularly difficult, but it is not immediate.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{H}$ is separable, the Schauder basis is countable. This means that for any $x \in \mathbb{H}$, there is a sequence $x_n \to x$ where each $x_n$ lies in a finite dimensional subspace spanned by a finite number of basis elements.

Since the basis is orthonormal, we can give a convenient, explicit
expression for such an $x_n$, in particular
$x_n = \sum_{k \le n} \langle e_k , x \rangle e_k$.

Uniqueness follows from the following: If a continuous linear operator $L$ satisfies $L e_k = 0$ on a Schauder basis $e_k$ then $L=0$. To see this choose some $x$ and let $x_n$ be the sequence
above, we see that $Lx_n = 0 $ and hence $Lx = 0$ by continuity.

Hence if $T,T'$ are continuous linear operators that agree on $e_k$ then we must have $T=T'$ (choose $L=T-T'$).

For convenience, let me use the notation $y(k) = \langle e_k , y \rangle$.

Existence needs a little more work. Define
$Tx = \sum_k x(k) h_k$, then
$\|Tx\|^2 = \sum_n \langle e_n , Tx \rangle^2 = \sum_n \langle e_n , \sum_k x(k) h_k \rangle^2 = \sum_n (\sum_k x(k) h_k(n))^2$.
Note that $(\sum_k x(k) h_k(n) )^2 \le (\sum_k |x(k)|^2) \sum_k (h_k(n))^2$ from which we get
$\|Tx\|^2 \le (\sum_n \sum_k (h_k(n))^2) \|x\|^2 = (\sum_k \sum_n (h_k(n))^2) \|x\|^2 =(\sum_k \|h_k\|^2 ) \|x\|^2$ and so
$\|T\| \le \sqrt{\sum_k \|h_k\|^2}$. Hence $T$ is continuous and
$T e_n = h_n$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to usurp Alex's answer, I was just curious why you thought the uniqueness was the main issue when existence is a little trickier.